# Why is Padrino trying to use a template when rendering a json response?

Tags: ajax, json, padrino

I have adopted a padrino application [[repo](https://github.com/CamJN/arewesmallyet/tree/ajax-data)], and am looking to move all the data into a json returned ajax call. From googling around I've seen:

- [Padrino model from json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386446/padrino-model-from-json-data/8386506#8386506)
- http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/controllers#provides-formats

So I created this [method/response](https://github.com/CamJN/arewesmallyet/commit/039fe7a0fa2671035c0a11fd59bc87e6166f4361) to try and start moving the data to a separate response:

```
get :data, provides: :json do
  @records = Record.order(:day).all
  render @records, layout: false
end
```

This results in a template not found error:

```
Padrino::Rendering::TemplateNotFound at /data.json
Template '#<Record:0x007fd19decdeb8>' not found in '~/Developer/Ruby/arewesmallyet/app/views'
```

and

```
Padrino::Rendering::TemplateNotFound at /data
Template '#<Record:0x007fd19decdeb8>' not found in '~/Developer/Ruby/arewesmallyet/app/views'
```

which doesn't make sense, obviously I don't want to use a template here, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I got it to work by replacing `render @records, layout: false` with `@records.to_json`.

Pretty sure that's not how it's supposed to work, so if anyone knows a better way I'm all ears, otherwise I'll accept this answer.

Comment: I am also new to Padrino. I have been following the to_json approach to  pass the json response. If there is any error, I would use halt method with the error code and return json. Just go through halt method. I couldnt find any other way to render json.